# On the newsletter preview window have an option at the end to subscribe to it

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, newsletter

The user experience of the preview is a little clunky, you look at a newsletter, let say you like it, you have to close the preview and then subscribe. Not major, but will make a smoother UI IMHO